# Preventing Tray Failover On HP Laserjet Enterprise M606

Tags: printer, hp-laserjet, paper-tray

I've looked at HP's support site for information regarding and HP Laserjet Enterprise M606, and downloaded a user manual. Still, I could not find the topic of printing failing over to another tray.

Our payroll department keeps one kind of regular form printing in Tray 3, and another form in Tray 2. When Tray 3 runs out of forms, Payroll doesn't want printing to continue from Tray 2.

I modified *Use another tray*, which is under *Administration Manage Trays* to *disabled*. Is that the correct way to prevent failover to another tray?

Comment: Sounds right. Have you tried it? HP's manuals are as useless as usual: they tell you everything you don't need a manual for.

Comment: @hdhondt I'll post back here, when our Payroll department tries this.

Comment: @hdhondt Want to answer it? You're correct. That's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is contained in the OP. I heard from our Payroll department that setting *User another tray* to *disabled* achieved our goal of not having a tray with one kind of Payroll form, failover to another tray with a different kind of form.